# Convert Json to Array fails

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

Json ($json):

```
string(387) "{"text":"Yahoo (eigene Schreibweise ''YAHOO!'') ist ein [[USA|US-amerikanisches]] Internetunternehmen mit Sitz in [[Sunnyvale (Kalifornien)]]. Mit \u00fcber 700 Millionen Nutzern weltweit z\u00e4hlt Yahoo zu den erfolgreichsten und gr\u00f6\u00dften [[Webportal]]en. Gegr\u00fcndet wurde das Unternehmen von [[David Filo]] und [[Jerry Yang (Unternehmer)|Jerry Yang]] im Januar 1994."}"
```

Php:

```
print_r(json_decode($json, true)); //returns NULL
```

I don't know why. I got the Json code from a API via `file_get_contents`.

Comment: does the string contain `string(387) "{"text":"This is a example."}" ` or just `{"text":"This is a example."}`

Comment: An abstract example won't tell. Make a hexdump. Validate your JSON somewhere beforehand.

Comment: @Augwa Its very crazy. If i open the URL i got the string from, there is no string(387). But if i got it via file_get_contents there is a string(387)

Comment: @mario i added the original text.

Comment: hmm can you post the code you use to get the string up until the point you do `json_decode` on it. It seems like a `var_dump()` is being used.

Comment: Sorry i forgott it. I just would to see what is in the content which i got via file_get_contents yes with a var_dump(). If i print it via print_r() it's without the string(387). But i get also the NULL result if i print it after decoding.

Comment: A hexdump. Just looking at it in a text editor or copy and pasting will not reveal the culprit.